# Удалён и преобразован в комментарий участниками

Tags: дефект, локализация

Встретил сообщение:

> Этот ответ скрыт. Он был удалён и преобразован в комментарий 3 часа назад участниками A K♦.

> [image: скриншот]

- Почему "участниками" во множественном числе?
- И может тут тоже надо менять участника на модератора?

Comment: Это общий шаблон, если кто-то из участников с достаточной репутацией подаст голос за удаление, а потом проголосует модератор -- то будет написано именно участниками с перечислением через запятую голосовавших.

Comment: @AK, но участники же не могут преобразовывать в комментарий - только удалять. PS: По-моему тебе надо пробел в нике заменить на неразрывный ;)

Comment: [Попросил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341931/260198) множественные формы добавить строке.

Answer (score 1):

В [оригинале](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13861) там **by**, а потом переменная **$deletingUsers$**. Множественных форм у фразы нет.

Я не уверен, что будет, если за удаление ответа проголосует участник, а потом модератор перенесёт в комментарии. Если там только ник модератора будет, тогда можно было бы и поменять на "модераторами".

С другой стороны, модераторы тоже являются участниками сообщества. Так что, предлагаю оставить как есть.

Comment: А мне больше не нравится множественное число.

Comment: @Qwertiy если придумаешь вариант перевода, чтоб охватить все варианты, то с радостью поменяю)

Comment: Если там только модератор, то он всегда один)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight лучше напишите ответом. А по голосам потом выберем)

Answer (score 0):

> ...converted to a comment $deletionDatePreSpan$$deletionDate$$deletionDatePostSpan$ by $deletingUsers$

Я на автомате предложил множественное число из-за "Users", но думаю можно by перевести пустотой:

> ...преобразован в комментарий $deletionDatePreSpan$$deletionDate$$deletionDatePostSpan$  $deletingUsers$

"... преобразован в комментарий 3 часа назад A K♦"

"... преобразован в комментарий 3 часа назад User, Moderator♦" в гипотетической ситуации, когда задействованы несколько участников

Раньше вроде так и было.

Comment: Тут падеж не согласуется. "преобразован в комментарий 3 часа назад Пётр" - фигня какая-то.

Comment: @Qwertiy по-хорошему, надо добавлять множественные формы тут. Я думал, что у меня уже был соответствующий FR на MSE, но нашел только по меткам похожий запрос: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305961/339911